# Codenames Pictures but with more surreal, colourful paintings

Tags: identify-this-game

We all know [Codenames](https://www.czechgames.com/en/codenames/) and [Codenames: Pictures](https://czechgames.com/en/codenames-pictures/).

A few years ago at a [Snakes & Lattes](https://www.snakesandlattes.com/), I and a few others played a version of Codenames that was like Codenames: Pictures, but the images were very different.

Whereas Codenames: Pictures has monochromatic, mostly two-element drawings:

[image: Codenames: Pictures cards]

This one had more watercolour-style ones, perhaps like this:

[image: Watercolour painting]

Also, I seem to recall that the cards were portrait orientation, but maybe they were square like Codenames: Pictures.

After much searching, I've resigned myself to the likelihood that it's not Codenames, despite the fact that everyone who played it that day remembered it as such.

Does anyone know which one I might be thinking of? P.S. Snakes & Lattes has [a partner site](https://www.boardgame2go.com/login/index.html) that lists their board games to rent or buy (choose "Enter as Guest"), but a quick skim of their "Guessing" category turns up nothing too promising.

Comment: Might it have been [Dixit](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/39856/dixit)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was [Dixit](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/39856/dixit)!

BGG description: "Give the perfect clue so most (not all) players guess the right surreal image card."

> Whereas *Codenames: Pictures* has monochromatic, mostly two-element drawings ... this one had more watercolour-style ones ... Also, I seem to recall that the cards were portrait orientation ...

*Dixit card pictures posted at https://coalition.agileuprising.com/t/dixit-retrospective/399*
[image: Example of Dixit cards showing watercolour art style]

Dixit has some similar guessing elements to Codenames: Pictures. Both of them have have players try to find pictures out of an array that match a verbal clue.

Comment: Also, there are expansion packs for Dixit with a variety of weird picture styles.  And the Dixit cards are much larger and less sturdy than Codenames cards; they're more like heavy playing cards.

Comment: Update: Dixit the game is pretty weak, but these pictures make for a great Codenames: Pictures set.